# Why would an npm package not automatically install all of its dependencies?

Tags: npm

The NestJS framework integrates nicely with TypeORM, however running `npm i @nestjs/typeorm` produces `@nestjs/typeorm@6.2.0 requires a peer of typeorm@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself`.

Presumably there is a reason why installing `@nestjs/typeorm` would not automatically install the `typeorm` that it depends on, but I cannot think of what it might be.